# merge two nested org.json.JSONObject

Tags: java, json

I have two JSON object from `org.json`:   the first one is

```
json1 = {a: {b : {c: val1} } }
```

and the second is

```
json2= {a {b: {c2: val2 } } }
```

is there any way to merge this two object to have one object like this:

```
result = {a: { b: {c: val1, c2: val2 } } }
```

I don't have any idea about the keys of the two objects, so i need to loop dynamically over these objects and do the merge. Is there any built in method to do this trick. Thanks.

Comment: where does `c1: val1` come from?

Comment: @ScaryWombat it's c:val1 and not c1. it's a mistake, thnks for the ascertainment

Answer (score 0):

```
static JSONObject merge(JSONObject obj1, JSONObject obj2) {
    obj2.forEach((k2, v2) -> obj1.merge(k2, v2, (v1, _v2) ->
            v1 instanceof JSONObject && _v2 instanceof JSONObject
                    ? merge((JSONObject)v1, (JSONObject)_v2) : "conflict!!"));
    return obj1;
}
```