# Fastest Way to Merge Multilevel HashMaps

Tags: java, lambda, java-8

I have many Multilevel HashMaps in which deepest element is List. Number of Levels may vary.

Intuitively lets say first hashmap is

```
{
    "com": {
        "avalant": {
            "api": []
        }
    }
}
```

and second hashmap is

```
{
    "com": {
        "google": {
            "service": {
                "api": []
            }
        }
    }
}
```

After merge it should become

```
{
    "com": {
        "avalant": {
            "api": []
        },
        "google": {
            "service": {
                "api": []
            }
        }
    }
}
```

What is the best way to merge them ? Just iterate two maps at a time and combine would be good idea ?

Comment: You have Map<String, Object> ?

Comment: Yes it is Map<String, Object>

Comment: The declared typing is not helping much. Is there any maximum numbers of nested levels?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I combine two HashMap objects containing the same types?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4299728/how-can-i-combine-two-hashmap-objects-containing-the-same-types)

Comment: This should work with a bit of adaptation: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44895524/1553851

Comment: @LittleSanti there is no limits for levels actually

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would first go with a version that really works, and after that see if I need a faster version.

A possible solution would be a recursive approach something like this (removed Generics and casts for easier read):

```
// after calling this mapLeft holds the combined data
public void merge(Map<> mapLeft, Map<> mapRight) {
    // go over all the keys of the right map
    for (String key : mapRight.keySet()) {
        // if the left map already has this key, merge the maps that are behind that key
        if (mapLeft.containsKey(key)) {
            merge(mapLeft.get(key), mapRight.get(key));
        } else {
            // otherwise just add the map under that key
            mapLeft.put(key, mapRight.get(key));
        }
    }
}
```

Just noticed the lambda label. I do not see a reason to use a stream here. Converting this to a stream would it make only more complicated in my opinion.

Comment: It is neat solution. It is worth to mention that mapLeft holds the final value

Comment: @PujanSrivastava I've added a comment about the modifying of the argument. Thank you for the proposed edit. I'm a little bit concerned adding the mapLeft as return value. If a method returns an object I would expect a copy/fresh object. I think the intention of the method as it is right now is more clearer.